# Custom Image creation times out intermittently in IBM Cloud

Tags: python, rest, jenkins, ibm-cloud

I am using this automation to create the image which waits for two hours before times out. On average the image creation takes around 7 8 minutes.
Using the same raw image and parameters image is created successfully but fails sometimes. Operating system is Ubuntu Linux. Size is 7 GB or 14 GB.

Code Snippet :

````
```def retrieve_image_status(ibm_client, image_id, waits=5):
    for i in range(waits):
        try:
            time.sleep(min(PAUSE_TIME, 1 << i))
            response = ibm_client.get_image(image_id)
            if response.result["status"] == "pending":
                print(
                    f"Image creation for image {response.result['name']}"
                    f" is in progress....."
                )
            elif response.result["status"] != "available":
                raise RuntimeError(
                    f"Unexpected error: Status"
                    f" {response.result['status']} "
                    f" {response.result['status_reasons']}."
                )
            else:
                print(
                    f"Custom image creation succeeded at"
                    f" {response.result['created_at']}."
                )
                break
        except ApiException as e:
            if e.code == 502:
                print(f"Intermittent Network Issue {e.message}")
            else:
                raise e
    else:
        raise RuntimeError(f"{response.result['status']}Image import has timed out")
````

Getting called here :

````
```  ssm_client = create_ssm_client()
    api_key = retrieve_ibm_config(ssm_client)
    authenticator = create_authenticator(api_key)
    ibm_client = create_ibm_client(authenticator)
    service_client = create_service_client(authenticator)
    resource_group_id = retrieve_resource_group_id(service_client, dc_ibm_env)
    image_prototype = create_image_prototype(
        source_bucket, source_object, resource_group_id
    )

    try:
        images = ibm_client.list_images(name=source_object)
        if images.result["images"]:
            print(f"Image already exists with name {source_object}")
            image_id = images.result["images"][0]["id"]
            note_image_id(image_id)
        else:
            response = ibm_client.create_image(image_prototype)
            image_id = response.result["id"]
            retrieve_image_status(ibm_client, image_id, waits=TWO_HOURS)
            note_image_id(image_id)
    except ApiException as e:
        raise RuntimeError(
            f"Image creation status failed with error code {e.code} {e.message}"
        )
````

Failure :

04:45:30  Image creation for image de-engine-2021-08-30-02-03-5d86f4d1-245 is in progress.....
04:45:30  Traceback (most recent call last):
04:45:30    File "devops-gate/scripts/ibm-create-image/create_image.py", line 170, in 
04:45:30      create_image()
04:45:30    File "/var/tmp/jenkins_slaves/ops.jenkins/workspace/devops-gate/master/build-and-snapshots/ibm-snapshots/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1137, in **call**
04:45:30      return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
04:45:30    File "/var/tmp/jenkins_slaves/ops.jenkins/workspace/devops-gate/master/delphix-build-and-snapshots/ibm-snapshots/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1062, in main
04:45:30      rv = self.invoke(ctx)
04:45:30    File "/var/tmp/jenkins_slaves/ops.jenkins/workspace/devops-gate/master/build-and-snapshots/ibm-snapshots/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
04:45:30      return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
04:45:30    File "/var/tmp/jenkins_slaves/ops.jenkins/workspace/devops-gate/master/build-and-snapshots/ibm-snapshots/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 763, in invoke
04:45:30      return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
04:45:30    File "devops-gate/scripts/ibm-create-image/create_image.py", line 161, in create_image
04:45:30      retrieve_image_status(ibm_client, image_id, waits=TWO_HOURS)
04:45:30    File "devops-gate/scripts/ibm-create-image/create_image.py", line 113, in retrieve_image_status
04:45:30      raise RuntimeError("Image import has timed out")
04:45:30  RuntimeError: Image import has timed out

How to handle this issue in code. If I rerun the image gets created successfully.
I tried getting with IBM Cloud team to know what was the issue at that time when it failed after two hours. But they don't have logs and nothing relevant in my logs also.

This automation gets called by a Jenkins job.

Comment: What is the value of TWO_HOURS?

Answer (score 0):

Verify your results with the cloud console or the CLI by checking the status of the image.  If it is "pending" as the code suggests after 2 hours it is unlikely to complete.  There is nothing this code can do to get the image to move into the "available" state.

You could have an outer loop that keeps creating images until one succeeds.

Also: Open a support ticket indicating that the error is intermittent and you need to get down to root cause so you can run your automation reliably.

Comment: I later checked the image is not pending. It exists when I see from console.  I already opened the support ticket and there is retry block in jenkins job for this script also. 
My assumption is session or the API call gets stuck.